# IIS 7.0 - Occasional 404 Errors

Tags: iis-7, http-status-code-404

So it looks like we're running into a weird issue where we're seeing 404 errors on pages that exist.   We have some web services and regular MVC 3.0 pages that get hit that will normally return 200 as expected but occasionally they'll return a 404 error.

We haven't really be able to track it down in weblogs and nothing exciting in the eventviewer.   Any know where else I should take a look to try and track down this issue.

EDIT:
We found out what the issue was.  We ended up doing some error tracing within IIS and found out that the sub status was 13 which means the file that was being uploaded was too large for IIS to handle with our current configs.  Ended up being a bug in our code.

Answer (score 0):

Actions to investigate :

1. cache prior the web client
2. IIS 7.0 configuration (notably, expires options)
3. look at the code in master pages